# CSS transition lost after using state to control sub menu

Tags: css, reactjs

Before using the method below, the css used to do a nice transition with the menu item but it is now not doing it anymore, not it just jumps. Do I need to use some sort of react transition library or what would the solution be to get the transition to work.

I am not really sure what else to say because the question won't let me post if I don't write some more text...

```
        {data.map((v) => (
          <li
            key={v.id}
            onClick={() => setSideActive(sideActive !== v.id ? v.id : "")}
          >
            <div
              className={
                sideActive === v.id
                  ? `${styles.navList__subheading} row ${styles.row__align_v_center} ${styles.navList__subheading__open}`
                  : `${styles.navList__subheading} row ${styles.row__align_v_center}`
              }
            >
              <span className={styles.navList__subheading_icon}>
                <FaPlaneDeparture />
              </span>
              <span className={styles.navList__subheading_title}>
                {v.name}
              </span>
            </div>
            {sideActive === v.id && (
              <>
                <ul
                  className={
                    sideActive === v.id
                      ? `${styles.subList}`
                      : `${styles.subList} ${styles.subList__hidden}`
                  }
                >
                  {v.content.map((val) => (
                    <li className={styles.subList__item}>{val}</li>
                  ))}
                </ul>
              </>
            )}
          </li>
        ))}
```

CSS

```
  .navList__subheading__open:after {
    transform: rotate(315deg);
  }
  .navList .subList {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #262c43;
    visibility: visible;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 200px;
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  }
  .navList .subList__item {
    padding: 8px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    padding: 8px 30px;
    color: #D3D3D3;
  }
  .navList .subList__item:first-child {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .navList .subList__item:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .navList .subList__hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
    max-height: 0;
  }
```